# CPU Only at 40% during bake and render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, fluid-simulation, hardware

My render and bake have recently started going by excruciatingly slow.  My CPU is only at around 40%, and my GPU is sitting around 10 or 20%.  I've been rendering a rather simple scene for almost 12 hours, much higher than previous simple scenes.

I'm using the Cycles Render - I have it set to prioritize my GPU, and I've raised blender's priority in task manager - all to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: If it is set to GPU render it will **not** perform the actual render process with the CPU, it will only be used for task scheduling, texture loading etc.

Comment: Are you talking about a fluid sim bake, a texture bake or something else?

Comment: Cycles either uses CPU or GPU not both; unless you are using one of the latest experimental nightlies. If you are using GPU rendering CPU will mostly stay idle, and you can't really prioritize GPU tasks. If you are using CPU then your GPU is not expected to be very loaded.